# SQL Replace Function Replacing Too Many Parts Of A String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a SQL Update statement to replace parts of a string. The one scenario I can't get is to only replace the first part of the string before the colon. I want to make the simple change from the value S to S2.

```
Current String: S:S:S;S:S:S
Wanted String: S2:S:S;S:S:S
```

SQL that I currently have:

```
UPDATE [table]
    SET [column] = REPLACE([cell], 'S:', 'S2:')
    WHERE [cell] LIKE  'S:%'
```

This produces the value S2:S2:S;S2:S2:S

Fields in [] are programmatically handled variables. I'm just struggling with the SQL part.

Comment: You should look into using STUFF. Is the first element always S:?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sean. S, in this case, is only an example. Any string could be passed into the query. However, these queries are being executed by a C# application and I can use that logic to programmatically find the length of the value to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

You see to want `STUFF()`:

```
UPDATE [table]
    SET [column] = STUFF([cell], 1, 2, 'S2:')
    WHERE [cell] LIKE  'S:%';
```